# Azure Data Factory: Move data from Google Bigquery to Azure Blob

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory. How can I move data from Google BigQuery to Azure Blob incrementally.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add more information to your question and what you've tried so far. I'm assuming by "Blob" you mean GCS?

Comment: to the Blob, which is in ADF, want to move data from Bigquery to blob through ADF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference this document: [Copy data from Google BigQuery by using Azure Data Factory](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery.md#copy-data-from-google-bigquery-by-using-azure-data-factory).

This article outlines how to use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data from Google BigQuery. It builds on the Copy Activity overview article that presents a general overview of the copy activity.

You can copy data from Google BigQuery to any supported sink data store. For a list of data stores that are supported as sources or sinks by the copy activity, see the Supported data stores table.

Azure Data Factory supports Azure Blob storage. To know more about Copy Actives, please reference [Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview).

In Azure Data Factory, you can use Copy Activity to copy data among data stores located on-premises and in the cloud.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can u please help me with the information regarding secret name, as I am unable to use refresh token, I am using AKV, where can I get the secret name?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know much about AKV. For this question, I think you can post new blog, then you can get more help or support from others.